# How to exclud rows and columns of a square array from calculations in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a 10*10 array for a domain

TT =

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

, but I need to exclude a square centered in the domain, so the new domain would be :

TT_new =

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0         0 0 0
0 0 0         0 0 0
0 0 0         0 0 0
0 0 0         0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I will create a for loop for the domain TT_new, how can I do this operation in MATLAB?

Clarification: I need the for loop to go through the "i,j" of the new domain "TT_new".

**For example,** I have the following mesh plot for steady heat conduction problem for a U-shaped plate:

[2D plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaVLl.png)

[3D plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsQQK.png)

I need to exclude the purple rectangular from the plot because it is not within the computational domain.

Comment: Loop through all `i`,`j` in `TT`. If `(i,j)` is in the center square, `continue` to the next iteration.

Comment: What operations do you do on the array? There are many different approaches you can use here, depending on what operations you apply on the other elements.

Comment: @CrisLuengo
Please have a look at the code

Comment: Have you thought about using a mask? You can't have matrices with holes in them, but if you element-wise multiply your original array with a matrix containing ones everywhere and zeros in the places you want to remove, your result will be an array containing the original numbers everywhere but zeros where you have zeros in your mask. Whether this is applicable to your situation depends on how you use the boundaries of your computational domain in your computation. Multiplying by a mask containing `NaN` will change unwanted elements to `NaN`.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi
Thanks, it really works, but can I have only one loop for the whole domain without dividing it into multiple regions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about using a mask?

You can't have matrices with holes in them, but if you element-wise multiply your original array with a matrix containing ones everywhere and zeros in the places you want to remove, your result will be an array containing the original numbers everywhere but zeros where you have zeros in your mask. For example:

```
my_arr = reshape(1:30, 5, 6);
my_mask = ones(5, 6);
my_mask(1:3, 3:4) = 0;

masked_arr = my_arr .* my_mask;
```

This gives:

```
my_arr = 
    1    6   11   16   21   26
    2    7   12   17   22   27
    3    8   13   18   23   28
    4    9   14   19   24   29
    5   10   15   20   25   30


my_mask = 
   1   1   0   0   1   1
   1   1   0   0   1   1
   1   1   0   0   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1   1

masked_arr = 
    1    6    0    0   21   26
    2    7    0    0   22   27
    3    8    0    0   23   28
    4    9   14   19   24   29
    5   10   15   20   25   30
```

Whether this is applicable to your situation depends on how you use the boundaries of your computational domain in your computation. Multiplying by a mask containing NaN will change unwanted elements to NaN.

Then, you could apply your mask before (or after, or both) every iteration to ensure that the unwanted elements are set to zero (or NaN, but that can cause problems if you add / subtract / multiply those elements with anything).

```
domain_mask = ones(size(T));
domain_mask(7:16, 12:31) = 0;

domain_mask_small = domain_mask(2:end-1, 2:end-1);

zero_row = zeros(1, size(T, 2));
zero_col = zeros(size(T, 1), 1);

while error > tol

    % Perform operations on the entire array
    T_iplus1 = [T(2:end, :); zero_row];
    T_iminus1 = [zero_row; T(1:end-1, :)];
    T_jplus1 = [T(:, 2:end), zero_col];
    T_jminus1 = [zero_col, T(:, 1:end-1)];
    
    T_temp = 0.25 * (T_iplus1 + T_iminus1 + T_jplus1 + T_jminus1);

    T(2:end-1, 2:end-1) = T_temp(2:end-1, 2:end-1) .* domain_mask_small;

    % Do whatever else

end
```